# Charts in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, chart.js

I need to create charts in an app, which uses Ionic 2. I searched the web but found some very scarce models. And also http://www.chartjs.org, but his documentation is very poor.

I mostly need donut charts, with click events. Or is it possible for me to have a click event on the chartjs donut chart? How can I do this?

Comment: if the solution is angular 2 (because ionic 2), I think so, my friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [**ng2-charts**](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/) which is a ChartJS wrapper for Angular 2/4.

Using this you can create a simple doughnut chart *(with click event)* as follows :

**template**

```
<div id="chart-container">
    <canvas baseChart 
          [chartType]="chartType"
          [data]="chartData"
          [labels]="chartLabels"
          (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

**component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

  public chartType: string = 'doughnut';
  public chartLabels: Array<string> = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'];
  public chartData: Array<number> = [1, 1, 1];

  public chartClicked(e: any): void {
    if (!e.active.length) return; //return if not clicked on chart/slice
    alert('Clicked on Chart!');
  }

}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/doughnut-chart)
<sub>( this shouldn't be too hard to implement in Ionic 2 )</sub>

<sub>**note:** this is just a basic example of a doughnut chart and you can customize it further to fit your need, following the [official documentation](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/#doughnutChart).</sub>

Comment: Thanks, my friend, I'm going to test my project to see if I can solve my problem.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible, I have the values of the area that I clicked, when I click? Example: if I click the blue, display in the "feb - 1"

Comment: You mean.. get the value (1) when you click on a donut slice (feb)?

Comment: Yes .. I need to have an ID, so I know where I clicked. Then I'll open a parameterized screen, based on the click.

Comment: Example: If I click on the area related to February, I'll call a function: openMonth (monthClicked)